# Multiplying two lists when the other list contains words as well

Tags: python, list

If I have a list `A` as follows: `A = [word, 5]` and other list `B` where `B = [4]`, how could I multiply only the numbers and come up with a list that is as follows: `new_list = [word, a * b]`?

Comment: What happens if you have a list with more than one number? Can you give us some more sample input/outputs?

Comment: what result do you expect from `A = ['word', 5, 'text']`, `B = ['string', 4]`?

Comment: Essentially I have a list where each index itself is a list containing one word and one number. Then I have one list containing only numbers and I'd like to multiply the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, int): #Checking if it is an int or not
        for j in b:
            if isinstance(j, int):
               c.append(i*j)
            else:
                if j not in c:
                    c.append(j)
    else:
        c.append(i)
```